# Write to text file problem in PHP

Tags: php

I have this page called up.php that adds 1 to a txt file set with all permissions.

```
<?php

$name = file_get_contents("name.txt");

if(!file_exists('number.txt')){
file_put_contents('number.txt', ((int) file_get_contents('number.txt')) + 1);
header('Location: "$name.txt");
} 

?>
```

I have a form action button that runs this php page, however the browser comes back with this:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /up.php on line 10.

I am lost here. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just have unbalanced quotes, change `header('Location: "$name.txt");` to `header('Location: "$name.txt"');`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a single quote in the header() line.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like you're missing a closing single-quote on the header() line.

Comment: Ah - I'm also _being_ slow. I did answer first, but who cares :)